# Django - use pdb interactive debug for wsgi running app

Tags: django, debugging, remote-debugging, pdb, django-dev-server

If I develop a Django app and use the included testing server, I can just add a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` anywhere in the code and have a breaking point that throws me into an interactive debugger. To make things clear, I dont' mean using any IDE, just simple setup of ssh-ing into a VM or remote dev server.

How can I get a similar behavior for an WSGI Django app? (again, the assumed setup is me with an ssh session to the server - VM or remote)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best my knowledge, if you want to use pdb with arbitrary a wsgi app, your best bet is to use [rpdb2](http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/).

(for Django on `mod_wsgi` with apache, you can refer to this guide: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques)

Comment: Based on link to rpdb2 I found nice way to debug things in django running eg. gunicorn http://stackoverflow.com/a/23106910/479931 . Thanks @KayZhu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that WSGI servers will use multiple processes and detach or redirect the standard streams - in, out, and <del>shake it all about</del> err.

For Apache httpd and mod_wsgi:

- Start with `apachectl -X`, not `apachectl start` (nor `service apache2 start`, etc.)
- Do not use `WSGIDaemonProcess`, `WSGIProcessGroup`, etc.
  You may need to add `WSGIPythonHome`, `WSGIPythonPath`, etc. to replace the daemon properties.

Similarly, for gunicorn you need the settings `debug=True` and `daemon=False`.

---

The [mod_wsgi guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques) recommends wrapping `wsgi.application` with a class, invoking pdb at the start of every request, but any other traps should work.

```
class Debugger:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.__object = object

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb, sys
        debugger = pdb.Pdb()
        debugger.use_rawinput = 0
        debugger.reset()
        sys.settrace(debugger.trace_dispatch)
        try:
            return self.__object(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            debugger.quitting = 1
           sys.settrace(None)

application = Debugger(application)
```

Comment: For mod_wsgi better off using ``mod_wsgi-express`` and then use the ``--enable-debugger`` to ``start-server``. It does everything to allow you to use the debugger.