# Django Gunicorn Debug

Tags: django, debugging, wsgi, gunicorn, pdb

Initially I had a Django app with the included testing server. To debug this setup, I can just add a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` anywhere in the code and have a breaking point that throws me into an interactive debugger in Terminal (on command-line).

Recently I shifted to gunicorn to gain some perf benifits. How can I get a similar behavior while using this Gunicorn setup. I have tried by setting gunicorn settings with `debug=True` and `daemon=False` but it does not work.

Anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: Did you find out how to make it work?

Comment: yes, please read my answer. this is what I do now...

Comment: I managed to use gunicorn and ipdb together. see my answer below. I also suggest setting the timeout to a bigger value, so you have time to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run green unicorn in a reverse proxy configuration (under nginx) in a debugger / debug mode, enter the following settings in [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)'s Run / Django / Edit configurations:

Of course, use whatever port (instead of `7777`) you have configured your nginx to proxy to.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what using GUI for python :D?

Comment: This doesn't really help. op wants to use `pdb`, not PyCharm's GUI to debug.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I've recently stumbed upon similar problem. I wasn't able to apply @dudklein solution (I get I/O Errors while debugger was trying to take input - ipdb, pdb etc.)

I used remote python debbuger - [winpdb](http://winpdb.org) and it's [embedded debugging](http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/).

1. install winpdb in Your virtualenv

   ```
   pip install winpdb
   ```
2. import and run embedded debugger in Your code:

   ```
   import rpdb2
   rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('pass')
   ```
3. run gunicorn with --timeout argument

   ```
   gunicorn -t 3600 env:application
   ```
4. run proper view using browser eg. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/your-view/`
5. connect to embedded debugger using winpdb:

   ```
   winpdb -a /path/to/django/app/views.py
   ```

   It will prompt You for a password (use one You set in Your code, in my example it is 'pass') and run nice GUI with debugger.
6. if You need tutorial for `winpdb` - [here You are](https://code.google.com/p/winpdb/wiki/DebuggingTutorial).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to launch gunicorn pointing at an `application` instance that is an instance of the `DebuggedApplication` class from the `werkzeug` library, you will be able to set break points using the werkzeug debugger with `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` right in your browser.

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
application = DebuggedApplication(application, evalex=True)
```

Make sure you install werkzeug library and ipdb of course. (`pip install werkzeug` and `pip install ipdb`)

Comment: @calvin-cheng: Not sure how this is supposed to work. First I should get an unhandled exception so the Werzeug traceback debugger becomes visible in the UI (i.e. Web Browser). That works. From them command line in the UI I call import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(). This causes an exception, looks to me that ipdb does not like its console (it seems to be some HTML* class, which doesn't sound completely wrong when it should work in the browser.)

Answer (score 2):

I managed now to use gunicron with djnago and ipdb.

run `python -m ipdb manage.py run_gunicorn --debug -t 3600`

I'm using Django 1.4 and gunicorn 0.16.1. then you can normally use the `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in the code. There is no need for the `werkzeug` library.

I'm trying to debug a facebook app, so I can't use the build in development server, because facebook tries to use SSL and the dev server just can't respond properly

While I was looking for a solution, I found a post [pdb: Using the Python debugger in Django](https://mike.tig.as/blog/2010/09/14/pdb/) that suggests to run `python -m pdb manage.py runserver` all the time. Although this is not necessary with django's dev server, I decided to give it a try with gunicordn and ipdb and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally ended up doing is run `python manage.py runserver <your_external_IP>:8000` when I want to use `pdb`.

So you need to have 2 different repositories in the same machine, one being LIVE production build (the one running `gunicorn`) and the other being the TEST build, the one I need to debug on where I use `pdb`. When things seem stable on TEST build I merge the `TEST branch` with `LIVE branch`. No development or changes happen on `LIVE branch` that way I avoid merge conflicts.

Hopefully this helps others who are addicted to `pdb` ;)

Comment: This actually does _NOT_ work if you have https reverse proxy (e.g. nginx)

Comment: @Kimvais yes you are correct. if you know how to do this in presence of a reverse HTTP proxy, I am interested to know the setup...

Comment: I only know how to do that in PyCharm, put will post as an answer