# Manage.py is exiting without any output

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I am attempting to upgrade a django 1.10 project to 2.2. My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.5.2 Django is now 2.2 and is running under gunicorn 1.19 with PostgreSQL and Redis.

So far, I have removed all the versions flags from the requirements.txt, and re-installed everything using pip. I'm working in a vagrant environment, so I'm rebuilding the whole vm every time I make any changes to the config.

When I try and start Gunicorn it seems to work, but looking at the logs I can see the workers are constantly starting and dying without logging anything either in log files or the console.

I'm now trying to run manage.py directly and I see it just exit without any exceptions, crash logs or similar. I know it's at least parsing the settings.py - I can make it crash deliberately and I see the exception as expected.

I've tried debugging with pdb - and it leads me to believe that it's crashing trying to import a module, but I'm not getting any information about which module. pdb also suggests that the manage.py is terminating with a sys.exit() - no error code, but I can't get any more information. I've even tried monkey-patching sys.exit() to give me some more context, but that hasn't worked either.

I've tried running python with -vv and there are no errors being reported - and I don't see any problems with any import statements.

Anyone seen anything like this?

UPDATE - I've now managed to complete the upgrade using a slightly less big-bang approach.

Comment: what does `$?` give after you run the manage.py file

Comment: Django 1.10 to 2.2 is a large jump. Get your code working with Django 1.11 first, fix any problems or deprecation warnings, and then try upgrading to 2.2.

Comment: Is debugging turned on in settings.py? Also, have you tried debugging [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210715/django-gunicorn-debug) ?

Comment: $? gives : -bash: 0: command not found

Comment: @Alasdair I know it's a large jump, but I was hoping that it would crash in a way that gives me a hint as to what's gone wrong...

Comment: @Alex W - debug is set True in settings.py if that's what you mean? In terms of actual debugging - I'm ssh-ing onto the vm, so using pdb is working - or at least kind-of working.

Comment: @AJFleming could you please post the solution as an answer, if you solved this?